# RestTemplate.getForObject handle an exception 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am doing about sso and using restTemplate.getForObject to receive token from server. But the result always handle exception not found although in server I printed the value of token. Server is at 8081 port. Below is my code

Api:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getJwtToken", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getJwtToken() {
    System.out.println("token store " + this.jwtTokenStore); //Here it printed: token store eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0c3NvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU2NTYxMDc2fQ.ga7vQ81NwFY8d84fWOfBMtsIhWgzyUo5ymWFi1s6juU
    return jwtTokenStore;
}
```

Client:

```
RestTemplate rest1 = new RestTemplate();
try {
        String getJwtTokenFromServer = rest1.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/getJwtToken", String.class);
        System.out.println("jwtFromServer: " + getJwtTokenFromServer);
        if(getJwtTokenFromServer != null) CookieUtil.create(response, jwtTokenCookieName, getJwtTokenFromServer, false, -1, domainClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

It always printed e.toString value.

Comment: what is "e.toString" prints on console?

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null

Comment: i fixed this by add @ResponseBody in my api. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Rest endpoint path "http://localhost:8081/getJwtToken" might be incorrect. if you  define @RequestMapping at controller level or 'server.servlet.contextPath' in properties file, you need to include that in uri.